# How does this work with Return Value Optimization?

Tags: c++

```
vector<int> f(const vector<int>& v)
{
    vector<int> ret(v.size());
    fill(ret.begin(), ret.end(), 123);
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ret.begin());
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v(10);
    v = f(v);
}
```

If return value optimization is applied to f, then the local variable ret shares the same address as v in main. But if this is true, filling ret will trash the data in v before the copy. The code is correct without RVO and optimizations shouldn't break behavior.

Is this safe or do I not understand RVO correctly?

Comment: There are two different kinds of return optimization: The copy from `ret` to the temporary to return from `f`, and the copy from that temporary into `v`. Only the former is allowed to be elided here.

Comment: Its possible the compiler will optimise away the whole fill line anyway

Comment: @OllieB Perhaps but this was just a simple example I made up.

Comment: @OllieB consider the definition of `f()` in a different compilation unit.

Comment: @DyP: You're right; I glossed over the start of the clause where it said it was specifically talking about construction and not assignment.

Comment: @NeilKirk: *Is this safe or do I not understand RVO correctly?* The latter. Shameless self-references [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-nrvo.html) and [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-copy-elision.html)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas You are a bit late to the party.

Comment: @NeilKirk: seems so, but the links might be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens is this:

On the caller's side, a return slot is provided which can hold the result, that means that the caller provides the *memory* for the variable of type `std::vector<int>`. It expects the called method to construct the value and is itself responsible for calling the destructor when the result is no longer used and freeing the memory (if necessary, it probably just lives on the stack).

The called function (which may live in a different translation unit!) would, without the NRVO, so this:

- Provide a memory slot for `ret`.
- Construct a local variable `ret` in this memory slot.
- Do stuff...
- Copy-construct the return value in the provided memory slot by copying `ret`.
- Call `ret`'s destructor.

Now, with the NRVO, the decision to optimize this can be done **in the called function's translation unit**. It transforms the above into:

- Construct `ret` in the memory of the method's return slot.
- Do stuff...

No need to do anything else as the memory is owned and the destructor is called by the caller and because the optimization is transparent for the caller :)

This, of course, can't eliminate the assignment into `v` in your example. If you store the result in a different variable, e.g.

```
std::vector<int> w = f(v);
```

the NRVO will construct `ret` directly into `w`'s memory (as this will be passed in as the return slot to `f`).

Comment: RVO can never eliminate the assignment copy?

Comment: @NeilKirk No. The assignment operation is always executed. Only direct initialization of a variable (which happens to have a `=` in its syntax) could do that, but true assignment can not be optimized away with the (N)RVO.

Answer (score 5):

The code is correct, your understanding of RVO is not - specifically this:

```
the local variable ret shares the same address as v
```

It doesn't share the address of the variable you assign it to. Technically, when you return an automatic local variable, it will be copied to a temporary. RVO skips *that* part.

It goes like this:

```
         create variable `ret`
                   |
 copy ret to a temporary before returning
                   |
       assign the temporary to v
```

NRVO (in this case) would skip the second part.

Compilers are smart though, so don't be surprised if it just optimizes the whole thing, since there's no observable behavior at all.

Answer (score 0):

RVO concerns construction of new objects.  Obviously, in main,
the compiler cannot pass `v` as the address of the return value,
since the function will *construct* a new `vector<int>` at this
address, and `v` has already been constructed.  So it will pass
the address of a temporary.  RVO concerns what happens in the
function: without RVO, the compiler would construct `ret`, and
then copy construct this into the address passed as a hidden
argument.  At the call site, if the return value is being used
to (copy) construct an object, then the compiler will skip the
copy of a temporary into the new object, and just pass the
address of the object to be constructed.  If the return value is
not being used as the argument of a copy constructor, however,
there isn't much the compiler can do.  You need an object of the
correct type, so it must generate a temporary.